# SWT Miglayout Problem

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, swt, miglayout

I'm using miglayout in my swt application but when the content of a text field is large it tends to push the width/height of the text field out of view, this issue also affects table component with many colums, how can this be prevented to ensure that the components stays within the available width of the shell.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add `wmin 0`to the layout data of your text. See [here](http://migcalendar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3186&view=next) for clarification.

In my opinion this issue is the biggest source of frustration for newcomers to Miglayout on SWT.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Miglayout for Swing. 
I needed to add wmin pref+10 to the layout constraints